# Automapper Map Nested List Object to Same Object as Parent

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, automapper

I have three objects, `Parent`, `Child`, and `NewObject`. Due to some intermediary work while I deprecate fields in `Parent`, `Child` is basically identical to `Parent`. Currently, `Parent` maps to `NewObject` just fine, but I also need to map the inner list of `Child` objects within `Parent` to `NewObject` so the mapping returns a list of `NewObject`. An example is below

```
public class Parent {
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child {
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class New {
    public string NewCode { get; set; }
    public string NewName { get; set; }
}
```

so if I had the following `Parent` object:

```
{
    "code": "abcd",
    "name": "parent",
    "children": [
        {
            "code": "efg",
            "name": "child1"
        },
        {
            "code": "xyz",
            "name": "child2"
        }
    ]
}
```

when I map it to `NewObject`, the result should be

```
[
    {
        "newCode": "abcd",
        "newName": "parent"
    },
    {
        "newCode": "efg",
        "newName": "child1"
    },
    {
        "newCode": "xyz",
        "newName": "child2"
    }
]
```

Is there a way to do this using solely Automapper? or do I need to use extra methods instead?

Comment: This is very easy to do by getting rid of AutoMapper. Do a manual mapping - just a couple lines of code. With AutoMapper, it will be dozens lines of code. Truly, this library creates more problems than it solves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no straight forward way to do this, without `AutoMapper` you can try something like this.

```
public static List<Child> ToNew(Parent parent)    {
    List<Child> result = parent.Children.ToList();
    result.Insert(0, new Child{
        Name = parent.Name, Code = parent.Code
    });
    return result;
}
```

This will give you `List` of `Child` objects, then you can map it to `List` of `New` objects.

```
CreateMap<List<Child>, List<New>>();
```

***Or*** you can use `AutoMapper` as follows. First add following mappings to your mapping profile.

```
public class MappingProfile : Profile
{
    public MappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Parent, List<New>>()
            .AfterMap((src, dest, context) => context.Mapper.Map(src.Children, dest));
        CreateMap<Child, New>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.NewName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Name))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.NewCode, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Code));
        CreateMap<Parent, New>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.NewName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Name))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.NewCode, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Code));
    }
}
```

Then create the mapper using the profile.

```
// Manually create the mapper using the Profile
var mapper = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.AddProfile(new MappingProfile())).CreateMapper();
```

Now you can convert `Parent` to `List<New>` using

```
var myFlattened = mapper.Map<Parent, List<New>>(parent);
```

Map parent properties to `New` as well and insert it to the first list.

```
var myFlattenedParent = mapper.Map<Parent, New>(parent);
myFlattened.Insert(0, myFlattenedParent);
```

Full code is avalable [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jKmdJL).